# After Hybris 2211.8, we receive document is missing mandatory unique key field: id

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Earlier this year, we had an upgrade of Hybris version from 2011 to 2211. One of the developers from SAP updated the version to 2211 in our manifest.json. Last June 19, we had trouble running our indexes specifically the ones that use custom identity providers. The error we mostly encounter is "Document is missing mandatory unique key field: id". After several weeks of endless debug, we discussed this with the SAP developer and he pointed out the patch. It turns out that the patch we were using before was 2211.6 and 2211.8 was recently introduced. It was also worth noting that the patch was not specifically mentioned in manifest.json that is why it is using the latest patch. We are now rolling back the patch to 2211.6. Now my question is, why are we having this issue after 2211.8? We checked the patch notes but nothing stood out that could cause the issue. Can you please help so that we could fix it? I don't know if it is important but we are using 8.11 version for our Solr.